# Datasets are set to public but cannot be seen on webpage?

Tags: sql, ckan

So my issue is that all the datasets that I have are set to public, but they cannot be seen on the webpage, however, I can still go to them directly if I have the URL. I figured out that if I go to manage the dataset and set it to private THEN set it back to public, it will then show up normally.

I don't understand why it does not automatically show up on the webpage without me having to go through the hassle of resetting the privacy.

Any thoughts? Is there a way I can go into the database's code and see if there is something wrong there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a Solr indexing problem. Datasets only show up on `/dataset` once they have been indexed in Solr. If they are public but not showing up there, then there is probably an indexing problem.

Try running the `paster search-index rebuild` command on your ckan instance. All the datasets that weren't showing up should show up.